# Whats the difference between NID_sha and NID_sha1 in Openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa, digital-signature

The manpage for RSA_sign() says about the type parameter:

```
type denotes the message digest algorithm that was used to generate m. It usually is one of NID_sha1, NID_ripemd160 and NID_md5; see objects(3) for details.
```

But I see another type available that is NID_sha in the Openssl source code.
Can someone please help me out with the difference between these two?

I am planning to use the RSA_Sign function to sign a digest of SHA-256, SHA-512 but i dont see the corresponding type parameter for SHA-256 and SHA-512 so what should I input for the type parameter in these cases.

For now I used the type as NID_sha and tried to sign a hash of SHA-256, SHA-512 and for both it works successfully that it  gives a proper signature and later signature verification is also proper , 
But i just would like to know what is NID_sha?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NID_sha` designates SHA-0, the direct ancestor of SHA-1. SHA-0 was originally called "SHA" but soon a modified version, called SHA-1, was published; the previous "SHA" was then declared obsolete, and is now traditionally called "SHA-0". The actual reason for the change was not made official, but it was generally understood that SHA-0 had some sort of weakness -- which was found by independent researchers a few years later, and used to produce collisions. Thus, SHA-0 is "broken" (much more than SHA-1) and you should not use it.

For RSA signing with SHA-256 you should use `NID_sha256` (for SHA-512, `NID_sha512`). If you use `NID_sha`, then you get a **wrong** signature. Internally, the signing process includes a transform where the hash value (the `m`/`m_len` parameters to `RSA_sign()`) is padded with a header which identifies the hash function (which is why `RSA_sign()` must have access to this information, through its `type` parameter). If you use `NID_sha` then this header will say "this is a SHA-0 hashed value, of length 32 bytes" which is doubly wrong: a SHA-0 hash value has length 20 bytes, not 32; and this is not a SHA-0 hashed value, but a SHA-256 hashed value.

So basically your signer produces a signature which departs from the official RSA signature standard ([PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125)). So your signature will not be verifiable with a compliant verifier. However, your verifier *also* departs from the standard, in the same way: by using `NID_sha` as parameter for `RSA_verify()`, you instruct the verifier to expect a "SHA-0" header (and a 32-byte hash value). This explains why things appear to work with your code: your verifier does the exact same mistake than your signer, and the two errors cancel out.

In other words, you are not signing with the true RSA, but a variant thereof, which, at first glance, is no less secure than the genuine thing, but still different and therefore not interoperable. Maybe this is not an issue in your specific situation, but, generally speaking, for cryptographic operations, you should stick to the letter of the standard (because security weaknesses are subtle things). If you use `NID_sha256` when you sign a SHA-256 hash value, then you get a standard-conforming PKCS#1 v1.5 RSA signature, and that is much better.

To sum up: forget `NID_sha`, use `NID_sha256` if the hash value comes from SHA-256 (`NID_sha512` for SHA-512), both for `RSA_sign()` and `RSA_verify()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Pretty much bulls eye answer.